# VisualStateManager not working inside Button.ContentTemplate UWP

Tags: xaml, button, uwp, visualstatemanager, contenttemplate

I have been struggling with this for a few days now unable to find solution after lot of effort. This is the code where I'm facing the issue. SO I have a `ItemsControl` where each element is `Button` and each `Button` has an `Image` and `TextBlock`. On hovering over `Button` I could see the `Background` of `Button` being changed to `Red` as expected. But I'm unable to change the `Foreground` of `TextBlock` to `Green`. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="Mini">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Mini.Background" Value="Red" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="MiniContent" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate" x:DataType="local:DataModel">
            <Button
                Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}">
                <Button.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DataModel">
                      <UserControl>
                        <Grid >
                           <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                      <Setter Target="Value.Foreground" Value="Green" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                               </VisualState>
                             </VisualStateGroup>
                          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Value"
                                Foreground="Yellow" 
                                Text="{x:Bind DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <Image
                                Width="16"
                                Source="{x:Bind ImageBitmap, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </Grid>
                       </UserControl>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </Button.ContentTemplate>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>

       
        <ItemsControl
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind DataModelVector, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you want to implement? There might be other ways to achieve it instead of using buttons.

Comment: I want to show a list of three apps one below another. For each app I want to show its image and appName. And on hover of app , I should be able to change background of entire item and foreground of appName. And on clicking the app I should be able to launch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something to actually transition between the VisualStates, the PointerOver state isn't triggered automatically. The easiest way would be to factor the content of your DataTemplate into its own file (UserControl with markup and code-behind) and handle pointer events in code to transition between visual states using VisualStateManager.GoToState.

You could also create a reusable "StateTrigger" for transitioning any control into a "PointerOver" visual state, but often some code-behind is simpler.